# Correcting whitespace count using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to do something like this:

Input:

```
"a     |    b"
"a|b"
"a| b"
"a |b"
```

Output for all of above Inputs must be:

```
"a | b"
```

I tried lots of things but couldn't achieve what I meant for.

Comment: Is | constant or it is any special charactor

Comment: If its happening many times in a single line, you'll need to give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will do as well:

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, "\\s*\\|\\s*", " | ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need regex for this.

```
var parts = myString.Split('|').Select(p => p.Trim());
var result = string.Join(" | ", parts);
```

As @I4V's answer shows you can split on carriage return line feed, then handle each row.

To use my answer in this way try this:

```
var splitLines = input.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var result = splitLines.Select(eachLine => string.Join(" | ", eachLine.Split('|').Select(p => p.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Regex.Replace(str, "([a-zA-Z]+)(\s*)\|(\s*)([a-zA-Z]+)", "$1 | $4");
```

I may be mistaking about $1,$4 location.  It may be "$4 | $5". Though it is not complete answer but may be close.

Answer (score -1):

> this happens many times in a multi-line text (Commented on a deleted answer)

```
string input = 
  @"a     |    b
    a|b
    a| b
    a |b";

var result = 
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
            input.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(line => String.Join(" ", Regex.Matches(line, @"\w|\|")
                                                   .Cast<Match>()
                                                   .Select(m => m.Value))));
```